# Máscara cartão de crédito com JSF

Tags: java, jsf, front-end, conversão, number-format

Gostaria de mascarar na tela o número de cartão de crédito do usuário para esse formato ######******####. Porém ao utilizar esse pattern ele empurra os números para a direita e não substitui. Alguém sabe se tem algum pattern que substitui o elemento? Estou utilizando assim.

```html
<h:outputText value="#{produtoBean.produto.numCartao}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="######******####"
</h:outputText>
```

Exemplo: Para o cartão 0123456789012345 ele esta mascarando assim: 012345******6789 e o correto seria 012345******2345.

Obs.: Não tenho a opção de formatar no back-end tenho que fazer no front.